# If you have $a_1$ and $a_{n+1}$, how can you find an (Arithmetic Sequence)?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in N}$ defined by $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 2n, n \in N$. Prove that $a_n = 3n − 2n, ∀n ∈ N$.

Comment: By induction? But isn't that $3n-2n=n$?

Comment: That's just wrong: $a_1=1,a_2=3+2=5, a_3=3\cdot 5 + 4=19$, how should $a_n=n$?

Answer (score 1):

The first three terms resolve to
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= 1 \\
a_2 &= 3+2=5 \\
a_3 &= 3\cdot 5 + 4 = 19
\end{align*}
so the result of $a_n=3n-2n$ is wrong. Nevertheless, you can find out the result by expanding, simplifying (maybe also guessing) the result and proving it as follows:

So let's expand the first few terms:
\begin{align*}
a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 2(n-1) &= 3(3a_{n-2} + 2(n-2))+2(n-1) \\
&=3^2a_{n-2}+3\cdot2(n-2)+2(n-1)\\
&=3^2(3a_{n-3}+2(n-3)) + 3\cdot2(n-2)+2(n-1) \\
&=3^3a_{n-3}+3^2\cdot 2(n-3) + 3\cdot2(n-2)+2(n-1)
\end{align*}

So, continuing this pattern, we can write $a_n$ as a sum which we will simplify at the end:

$$
a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 3^{i-1}\cdot 2(n-i) + 3^{n-1}
$$

Let's test if this works for $n=1,2,3$:
\begin{align*}
a_1&=3^{1-1}=1 \quad\checkmark \\
a_2&=\sum_{i=1}^1 3^{i-1}\cdot 2(n-i)+3^{n-1} = 2(2-1)+3^1=5 \quad \checkmark \\
a_3 &= 2(3-1)+6(3-2)+3^2=4+6+9=19 \quad \checkmark
\end{align*}

Now we want to simplify the above sum to get an easier form by changing/extending indices inside the sum and then by using specific forms of geometric progression (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression):
\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac 2 3\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}3^i(n-i) + 3^{n-1} \\
&= \frac 2 3n\sum_{i=1}^{n} 3^i-\frac 2 3 n 3^n - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} i3^{i-1} + 2n3^{n-1}+3^{n- 1} \\
&= \frac 2 3n\sum_{i=1}^{n} 3^i - 2 \left(\frac{1-3^{n+1}}{(1-3)^2}-\frac{(n+1)3^n}{1-3}\right)+ 2n3^{n-1}+3^{n- 1}-\frac 2 3 n 3^n \\
&= \frac 2 3n \frac{3-3^{n+1}}{1-3} - \left(\frac{1-3^{n+1}}{2}+(n+1)3^n\right)+ 2n3^{n-1}+3^{n- 1}-\frac 2 3 n 3^n \\
&= -n (1-3^n) - \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 2 3^{n+1} -(n+1)3^n+ 2n3^{n-1}+3^{n- 1}-\frac 2 3 n 3^n \\
&= \frac 1 2 3^{n+1} + (n-n-1-\frac 2 3 n)3^n + (2n+1) 3^{n-1} -n-\frac 1 2 \\
&= \frac 1 2 3^{n} - 3^n + (2n+1-2n) 3^{n-1} -n-\frac 1 2 \\
&= \frac 3 2 3^{n} - 3^n + \frac 1 3 3^{n} -n-\frac 1 2 \\
&= \frac 5 6 3^{n} -n-\frac 1 2
\end{align*}
and indeed, testing with $n=1,2,3$ yields the expected results, so the final solution is:

$$a_n=\frac 5 6 3^n - n - \frac 1 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence $a_n$ is obviously not $n.$ But let us compute it for fun.

The sequence $b_n:=\frac{a_n}{3^n}$ satisfies:
$$b_1=\frac13,\quad b_{n+1}=b_n+\frac{2n}{3^{n+1}}$$
hence
$$b_n=\frac13+\frac29
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac k {3^{k-1}}=\frac13+\frac29f'_n(1/3),$$
where $f_n(x)=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$ and $f'_n(x)=\frac{(n(x-1)
-x)x^{n-1}+1}{(x-1)^2}$ in particular
$f'_n(1/3)=\frac94(1-\frac{2n+1}{
3^n}),$ so that finally, $b_n=\frac13+
\frac12-\frac{2n+1}{2\cdot3^n}$ and
$$a_n=\frac56\,3^n-n-\frac12.$$